# Question about converting `void *` to `int` in C

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, pthreads

I'm trying to pick my C skills again. I want to sum a sequence in different threads, each thread would return a pointer of the sum of a part of the sequence. However, when I tried to convert the `void*` type value `local_sum` to `int`, problem occurred.

I tried to convert with `sum += *(int*)local_sum;`, a segment error occurred and I got `Process finished with exit code 11`.

I found that if I use `sum += (int)local_sum;`, it would be okay. But I couldn't convince myself: shouldn't `local_sum` be a `void *`? Why it can be converted to `int` with `(int)local_sum`?

I'm so grateful it you could answer the problem.

The part that sum each process's return value is here:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i ++) {
    void * local_sum;
    pthread_join(count_threads[i], (&local_sum));
    sum += (int)local_sum;
}
```

The function of a thread is here:

```
void * count_thr(void *arg) {
    int terminal = ARRAY_SIZE / NUM_THREADS;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < terminal; i ++) {
        sum += *((int*)arg + i);
    }
    return (void*)sum;
}
```

Comment: Passing an `int` inside the the `void*` of pthreads, as opposed to pointing at one, has always been a dirty hack. And as all dirty hacks, they eventually break. Integer-to-pointer conversions have implementation-defined behavior (at the very least use uintptr_t). The solution is not to use dirty hacks, but to pass a pointer to malloc:ed data. The overhead execution time of dynamic allocation is nothing compared to the cost of creating and closing a thread.

Comment: refer to [c89: Convert an int to void* and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042368/c89-convert-an-int-to-void-and-back) and the linked question [Is it safe to cast an int to void pointer and back to int again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568069/is-it-safe-to-cast-an-int-to-void-pointer-and-back-to-int-again)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're `return`ing the value of `int sum` by setting a `void *` address to it.  In this case, the address is not valid.  But, if you keep that in mind and get the value of `sum` by casting a `void *` to `int` it will work.

`void *` is used this way sometimes to `return` either a value (e.g. `int`) or an address to something (e.g. `struct`).

To illustrate this:

```
int a = 5;
void *p = (void *)a;
int b = (int)p;
```

`a`, `p`, and `b` all have a value of `5`.  `p` does not point to a valid address.  Trying to dereference `p` would result in undefined behavior:

```
b = *(int *)p; // Undefined Behavior!
```

Consider the following program:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    void *p;

    a = 5;
    p = (void *)a;
    b = (int)p;

    printf("%d %p %d\n", a, p, b);

    a = INT_MAX;
    p = (void *)a + 1;
    b = (int)p;

    printf("%d %p %d\n", a, p, b);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, I get the following warnings:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     p = (void *)a;
         ^
main.c:10:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     b = (int)p;

...
```

A warning is issued because, as pointed out by @Gerhardh, the `sizeof(int)` and the `sizeof(void *)` may be different.  You may suffer data loss if the value of the `void *` exceeds the maximum value a `int` can hold.

**Output**

```
$ ./main.exe
5 0x5 5
2147483647 0x80000000 -2147483648
```

Comment: " in our case, this behavior is desired." Really? It's not only a warning about conversion, it is about different size. That is not the part that is desired. You probably have 4 byte integers and 8 byte pointers.

Comment: note that the behavior of this is implementation defined

Comment: *a, p, and b all have a value of 5.* `a` and `b` are not guaranteed to have the same value.

Comment: @DavidBrown Of course, this is undefined behavior.  On my machine, this behavior is so.

Comment: @FiddlingBits : correction : it's [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042368/c89-convert-an-int-to-void-and-back) as I stated earlier. It will work on many (if not most) platforms as you describe, but is not guaranteed to.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do `*(int*)local_sum` because `local_sum` is not an `int*` cast to `void*`. `local_sum` is an `int` cast to `void*`. It is a number reinterpreted as an address, but only for transfer purposes, because `pthread_exit` only allows you to return a `void*`, not an `int` and because the standard explicitly allows implementation-defined conversion ([6.3.2.3p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5), [6.3.2.3p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6)) between integers and numbers as long as the values fit (if they don't then, UB). If you return, e.g., `0x42`, it is highly unlikely there's anything at address `0x42`, so you should forget about dereferencing it and instead you should convert it back to an integer ASAP, either with `(int)local_sum;` or perhaps better with `(int)(intptr_t)local_sum;` (though `intptr_t` isn't guaranteed to exist) or (perhaps best) with `(int)(intmax_t)local_sum;` so as to avoid possible compiler warnings about converting to an integer of a different size on LP64 platforms.

Answer (score 1):

A secure and portable solution could be the use of an union:

```
union void_cast {
    void* ptr;
    int value;
};
```

Then for example you can safely reinterpret a `void*` pointer with:

```
int VOID_TO_INT(void* ptr) {
    union void_cast u;
    u.ptr = ptr;
    return u.value;
}

void* INT_TO_VOID(int value) {
    union void_cast u;
    u.value = value;
    return u.ptr;
}
```

So your code can be changed to:

```
sum += VOID_TO_INT(local_sum);
```

Comment: Casting should work regardless of endianness. On a (very theoretical) big-endian machine where  ints are half the width of pointers, the union approach would fail to extract the value while a cast shouldn't.