# what does it mean to convert int to void* or vice versa?

Tags: c, void

What does it mean to convert an integer value to a `void*` or viceversa from a memory point of view?
My understanding is `void*` is an address to a block of memory of unspecified length.
This seems to be something like comparing apple with oranges.

```
int myval = 5;
void* ptr = (void*)myval;
printf("%d",(int)ptr);
```

I realized that I should have given the exact context where this is used.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
long       thread;  /* Use long in case of a 64-bit system */
pthread_t* thread_handles; 

/* Get number of threads from command line */
if (argc != 2) Usage(argv[0]);
thread_count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);  
if (thread_count <= 0 || thread_count > MAX_THREADS) Usage(argv[0]);

thread_handles = malloc (thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t)); 

for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)  
  pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, Hello, (void*) thread);  

printf("Hello from the main thread\n");

for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++) 
  pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL); 

free(thread_handles);
return 0;
}  /* main */

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void *Hello(void* rank) {
long my_rank = (long) rank;  /* Use long in case of 64-bit system */ 

printf("Hello from thread %ld of %d\n", my_rank, thread_count);

return NULL;
}  /* Hello */
```

This code is from Peter Pachecho's book on Parallel programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568069/is-it-safe-to-cast-an-int-to-void-pointer-and-back-to-int-again

Comment: It's even worse .. - at least like comparing apples to potatoes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Casting `int` to `void *` is rather meaningless and should not be done as you would be attempting to cast a non-pointer to a pointer.  Quoting the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), section 6.3.2.3 item 5:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.

You *could* cast `int *` to `void *` (any pointer is convertible to `void *` which you can think of like the "base type" of all pointers).

Casting `void *` to `int` is not portable and may be completely wrong depending on the platform you use (e.g. `void *` maybe 64 bits wide and `int` may only be 32 bits).  Quoting the C99 standard again, section 6.3.2.3 item 6:

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

To solve this, some platforms provide `uintptr_t` which allows you to treat a pointer as a numeric value of the proper width.

Comment: This "any pointer is convertible to `void *`" is wrong. It should be "any pointer to an object is convertible to `void *`". Casting function pointers to `void *` causes UB.

Answer (score 3):

Both `void*` pointer (or any pointer for that matter) and `int` are, roughly speaking, numbers. They may be of different bitsize, but it is unlikely that pointer is smaller than `int`, so that makes the operation reversible. Of course, it's illegal and you should never dereference the pointer that has no valid location to point to.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard specifies that it must be possible to convert a void pointer to an integral type such that converting the integral type back to a void pointer will yield the same pointer.  I'm not sure if it requires that converting a null pointer to an integer yield the value zero, or if only numeric literal zeroes are recognized as special.  On many implementations, the integer value represents a hardware address, but the standard makes no such guarantee.  It would be entirely possible that on hardware which included a special trap for hardware address 0x12345678, converting a pointer to an integer would subtract 0x12345678 from the hardware address, and converting an integer to a pointer would add 0x12345678 back in (thus an integer value of zero would represent a null pointer).

In many cases, particularly when developing for embedded controllers, the compiler vendor will explicitly specify what hardware address will be accessed when converting a particular integer value to a pointer type.  On processors with a single linear address space, converting an integer value 0x12345678 to a pointer would generally yield a pointer which refers to address 0x12345678; the hardware reference manual would indicate if there was anything special about that location.  On processors with more 'interesting' address spaces, it may be necessary to use something other than the hardware address as the pointer.  For example, on antique IBM PC computers, the display buffer was mapped at hardware address 0xB8000, but in most compilers, the address would be expressed as (short far*)0xB8000000.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite like comparing apples and oranges. The only way that this code works is because you are explicitly casting it back and forth.

The C compiler is just copying the bytes from the int into the space for the pointer and back, just like how you can hold a char in an int.

This could even cause your number to be messed up if for some reason an 'int' is longer than a 'void *' on your platform.

If you actually do want have a number to convert from integers into pointers and back, look into `intptr_t`. That type is actually designed to store both integers and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to be able to cast a pointer to integer type for pointer arithmetic. For instance, the `offsetof()` macro, which calculates the offset of a member within a structure, needs this kind of conversion.

However, it must be ensured that the primitive type used for this is able to handle a pointer: here, for 64 Linux for instance, when using gcc, this is not the case: `void *` has size 8, an int has size 4.

The `offsetof` macro is defined as such:

```
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
```

It is used prominently in the Linux kernel's doubly linked list implementation, very simply defined as:

```
struct list_head { struct list_head *prev, *next; }
```

This struct is embedded within kernel structures, as in:

```
struct something {
    //...
    struct list_head list;
    //...
}
```

When walking a list, the code needs to grab a pointer to the encoding structure. This is done as this (simplified definition):

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    (type *)((char *)ptr - offsetoff(type, member))
#define list_entry(list, type, member) \
    container_of(list, type, member)
```

And in the code, you will very often see:

```
struct something *s;
list_for_each(listptr, somehead) {
   s = list_entry(listptr, struct something, list);
   //...
}
```

which would simply not be doable without this kind of macro and pointer arithmetic. But it is very dependent on the toolchain.

Comment: What does this have to do with `offsetof`. Also, `offsetof` is platform defined, a compiler implementation is free to implement it which way it fits best. E.g gcc implements this by an intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

It would be like comparing apples with oranges if any attempt was being made to make any comparison. But there isn't. Basically, in the majority of architectures out there, an int can be casted to a void pointer without the loss of any information, and a void pointer can also be casted back to an int, again without the loss of any information. Of course, you should not try dereferencing that pointer, because it does not point to any meaningful memory location: it is just a variable containing the same bit-pattern as the bit pattern that the integer used to contain before the cast.

Comment: It is not true that there is no loss of information. The C99 standard says, "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type."

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer and corrected that mistake. (I edited out the bit about C99, and the word 'vast' in the term 'vast majority'.)

Comment: "Vast majority" is probably even false today, and will hold less and less likely in the future. Modern architectures are mostly with 64 pointers and 32 bit `int`.