# Cast int to void*

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I'm trying to create a void* from an int. But gcc always give me a warning, that i cannot cast an int to a void*. Here is my code:

```
#define M_TABLE_SIZE 64*1024
static const void* M_OFFSET = M_TABLE_SIZE;
```

I already tried `(void*)M_TABLE_SIZE` but then I get an error that I cannot use the `*` operator.

What is the correct method to cast an int to a void*?

Comment: May be helpful for you. [What does it mean to convert int to void* or vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618637/what-does-it-mean-to-convert-int-to-void-or-vice-versa)

Comment: `static const void* M_OFFSET = (void*)(M_TABLE_SIZE);`

Comment: Once you manage to make this cast, then what?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
static const void* M_OFFSET = (void*)M_TABLE_SIZE;
```

expands to

```
static const void* M_OFFSET = (void*)64*1024;
```

Since gcc compiles that you are performing arithmetic between `void*` and an int (`1024`). Put your define inside a bracket:

```
#define M_TABLE_SIZE (64*1024)
```

Now, you can do:

```
static const void* M_OFFSET = (void*) M_TABLE_SIZE;
```

without a problem. It's always a good practice to put your `#define`'s in brackets to avoid such surprise.

Unless you have a valid address at that value, you are going to invoke *undefined behaviour* when try to use that pointer. So make sure you understand what you are doing!

Comment: I guess the other important fact is that the cast operator has higher precedence that the multiplication operator

Comment: @BlueMoon Thanks a lot! I assumed that gcc makes a 65536 out of my define, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a fairly recent compiler (that supports C99) you should not store or represent address as plain `int` value. If you really need such trickery, then consider one of dedicated types, which are `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. Referring to N1570 7.20.1.4/p1 (Integer types capable of holding object pointers):

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property
>   that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then
>   converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal
>   to the original pointer:
>
> `intptr_t`
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
>   property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>   then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
>   equal to the original pointer:
>
> `uintptr_t`
>
> These types are optional.

In your case it might be:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define M_TABLE_SIZE ((intptr_t) (64*1024))
static const void* M_OFFSET = (void *) M_TABLE_SIZE;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are using a define, which is not a variable.
The preprocessor will replace your code by this:

```
static const void* M_OFFSET = 64*1024;
```

This is unlikely what you are trying to do.

You may declare a const int variable and cast its reference to the void*.

Comment: The preprocesor absolutely will not perform arithmetic

Comment: You are right! Thanks for pointing that out. Just edited. However, I believe that even if the define was for the "65536", it would not be what @kaetzacoatl wanted.