# (c++) Casting int to char pointer (int being character in int form)

Tags: c++, pointers

So basically I want to be able to do something along these lines

```
char *test1 = "hey";
int test2 = (int)test1;
char *test3 = (char*) &test2;
printf("%s", test3);
// have the output as hey
```

Is this even possible? I know this isn't working correctly but I just want to know if there's a working method. Yes I want to use char pointers and ints, so no, I don't want to use strings

Comment: [C++: Is it safe to cast pointer to int and later back to pointer again?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567905/c-is-it-safe-to-cast-pointer-to-int-and-later-back-to-pointer-again)

Comment: Note that `char *test1 = "hey";` should not compile.  Some compilers have an extension that allows this but you should use `char test1[] = "hey";` or `const char* test1 = "hey";` or better yet `std::string test = "hey";`

Comment: Is **what** even possible? You've written some code that does some iffy casts that may or may not do something sensible. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - while that's an important point, it's not really what's going on here. There's another level of indirection, initializing `test3` with `(char*)&test2`. Note the `&` -- it's taking the **address** of `test2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *test1 = "hey";
int test2 = (int)test1;
char *test3 = (char*) test2; // Note that the ampersand has been removed
printf("%s", test3);
```

might work if `int`s and pointers are the same size (they often are, but it's not guaranteed).

But when you assign `test3`, you are taking the *address* of test2, instead of its value, which is what I think you really meant to do.

Comment: Pointers are usually _unsigned_ integers.

Comment: Please check the answer as "accepted" if you want to give the deserved reputation to the user ;)

Comment: @AhmetIpkin this answer exhibits undefined behaviour and should not be accepted. casting a pointer to an int is undefined behaviour. casting a string literal to a pointer to mutable char is undefined behaviour. casting a string literal (indirectly) to a pointer to mutable char is also undefined behaviour.

Comment: @RichardHodges Casting a `char *` to an `int` is NOT an undefined behaviour (`std::intptr_t` is optional and most of the time is `uint_t`) , you are simply reading the address of the literal (modifying that address is UB). Castings are pretty well defined operations on C / C++. Casting a string literal to a char pointer is also NOT an UB, it is an ERROR in any sane compiler - which can be fixed with assigning to a `const char*`.

Comment: @AhmetIpkin this question is tagged c++.

Comment: @RichardHodges castings are still valid operations in C++.

Comment: @AhmetIpkin §5.2.10 (para 4) "A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is
implementation-defined." so to be exact, this operation is only well defined if an integer is at least as large as a pointer. This is often not the case. On all other matters, I stand by my reasoning. casting a string literal to a pointer to mutable chars is undefined behaviour. Therefore the entire program will exhibit undefined behaviour.

Comment: I am quite interested to see an architecture that a pointer is not the size of an unsigned integer. Besides, casting is never UB, _using_ that pointer might or might not, depending on usage.

Comment: The question was "Is this even possible". In my answer, I attempted to make the minimal change to allow the original code to run. And I did note the caveat that it requires that `int` and a pointer be the same size.

Comment: @AhmetIpkin In the 1980s, I used several compilers, mostly for MacOS, that had 16-bit `int`s and 32-bit pointers. IIRC, the old "Lightspeed C" was that way.

Answer (score 1):

The code represents undefined behaviour and is therefore incorrect.

There is, however a way to do what you want legally. See comments inline for explanations:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    // string literals are const
    const char *test1 = "hey";

    // intptr_t is the only int guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer
    std::intptr_t test2 = std::intptr_t(test1);

    // it must be cast back to exactly what it was
    const char *test3 = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(test2);

    // only then will the programs behaviour be well defined
    printf("%s", test3);
}
```