# Is sizeof(int) guaranteed to equal sizeof(void*)

Tags: c, sizeof

Is the size of the datatype "int" always equals to the size of a pointer in the c language?

I'm just curious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof (int) == sizeof (void\*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not at all, there is no guarantee that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)`. And on Linux/AMD64 `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, and `sizeof(void*)` is 8 bytes (same as `sizeof(long)` on that platform).

Recent C standard (e.g. C99) defines a standard header `<stdint.h>` which should define, among others, an integral type `intptr_t` which is guaranteed to have the size of pointers (and probably even which is reversably castable to and from pointers).

I think that the standard does not guarantee that all pointers have the same size, in particular pointer to functions can be "bigger" than data pointers (I cannot name a platform where it is true). I believe that recent Posix standard requires that (e.g. for [`dlsym`(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)).

See also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft C11 standard (or better)

PS. In 2021 I cannot name a common platform with `sizeof(long) != sizeof(void*)`. But in the previous century the old [intel 286](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80286) could have been such a platform.

Answer (score 3):

It is not guaranteed.

And for example, in most 64-bit systems both sizes are usually different.

Even `sizeof (int *)` is not guranteed to be equal to `sizeof (void *)`.

The only guarantee for `void *` size is

```
sizeof (void *) == sizeof (char *)
   == sizeof (signed char *) == sizeof (unsigned char *)
```

Comment: Do you know of a platform today where `sizeof(int*)` != `sizeof(void*)` ?? 25 years ago, it was true on some Cray YMP supercomputer. I know no current platform where it is true (or perhaps some DSP?).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch For Cray / UNICOS I knew some platforms that had different memory representation for `void *` (64-bit) and `int *` (32-bit), but the ones I knew of still had the same memory size in bits for these pointers (both 64-bit). The only other information I know is this c-faq link which lists some machines http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Answer (score 2):

No. for example, in most 64bit systems, int is 4 bytes, and void* is 8.

Answer (score 1):

No. Some (mostly older, VAX-era) code assumes this, but it's definitely *not* required, and assuming it is not portable. There are real implementations where the two differ (e.g., some current 64-bit environments use a 64-bit pointer and 32-bit int).

Answer (score 1):

The C languages gives no guarantees of anything when it comes to integer or pointer sizes.

The size of `int` is typically the same as the *data bus* width, but not necessarily. The size of a pointer is typically the same as the *address bus* width, but not necessarily.

Many compilers use non-standard extensions like the `far` keyword, to access data beyond the width of the default pointer type.

In addition to 64-bit systems, there are also plenty of microcontroller/microprocessor architectures where the size of int and the size of a pointer are different. Windows 3.1 and DOS are other examples.

Comment: `The C languages gives no guarantees of anything when it comes to integer or pointer sizes` - I believe C99 requires that an `int` must be able to hold -32767 through +32767 (C99, "Sizes of integer types" <limits.h> 5.2.4.2.1) - so that would imply that C guarantees a minimum of 16-bit-width for int.  No guarantees on max size, of course...

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee of any relation between the sizes of these two types, nor that either can be faithfully represented in the other via round-trip casts. It's all implementation-defined.

With that said, in the real world, unless you're dealing with really obscure legacy 16-bit systems or odd DSPs or such, `sizeof(int)` is going to be less than or equal to `sizeof(void *)`, and you can faithfully convert `int` values to `void *` to pass them to interfaces (like `pthread_create`) that take a generic `void *` argument to avoid wasteful allocation and freeing of memory to store a single `int`. In particular, if you're using POSIX or Windows interfaces already, this is definitely a safe real-world assumption to make.

You should **never** assume `void *` can be faithfully represented in `int` (i.e. casting a pointer to `int` and back). This does not work on any popular real-world 64-bit systems, and the percentage of systems it works on is sure to plummet in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Pointer types do not have to be the same size or representation as integer types.  Here are a few relevant sections from the C language standard (online draft available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)):

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 27 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
> pointer to a character type.<sup>39)</sup> Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
> as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
> alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
> representation or alignment requirements.
> ...
> 39) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as
> arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.
> ...
> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 5 An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
> entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.<sup>56)</sup>
> 6 Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
> the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
> type.
> ...
> 56) The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
> be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't have to be, but it's usually the case that `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)`.