# Is sizeof(int) always equal to sizeof(void*)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sizeof (int) == sizeof (void*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void)

I was wondering whether it is guaranteed that, in both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int)` is always equal to `sizeof(void*)` (i.e. 32 and 64 bits respectively).

Additionally, I need to know whether it is always guaranteed that a `long int` can accommodate the bits of an `int` and a `void*` together, e.g.

```
long int lint = (((int)integer)<<sizeof(int)) | (void*)ptr;
```

Comment: `long int` and `int` actually have the *same* size on many platforms.

Comment: The first and foremost reason `(((int)integer)<<sizeof(int)) | (void*)ptr` will never work is that `<<` shifts bits and `sizeof(int)` is expressed in bytes.

Comment: it is guaranteed that sizeof (long int) >= sizeof (int)

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what you were *really* trying to accomplish, we could answer with some more accurate solution.

Comment: @AndréCaron: "No" is pretty accurate :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "No" is definitely accurate, but it's not a solution.  At least, not to whatever OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AndréCaron: This is a programming Question & Answer site, not a Problem & Solution site :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't see the point in answering the question if it doesn't solve OP's problem.

Comment: @AndréCaron: The OP has not stated a problem. The OP has asked a question. The OP will gain knowledge from the answer to the question. Pretty simple stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering whether it is guaranteed that, in both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, sizeof(int) is always equal to sizeof(void*) (i.e. 32 and 64 bits respectively).

No.

> Additionally, I need to know whether it is always guaranteed that a long int can accommodate the bits of an int and a void* together

No.

What you are looking for is: std::intptr_t

```
sizeof(std::intptr_t) == sizeof(void*)
```

std::intptr_t is defined as an integer of a size sufficient to hold a pointer.

Technically its optional part of the standard.
But you can usually find in the header file `<cstdint>` See: `18.4.1 Header <cstdint> synopsis [cstdint.syn]`

Answer (score 7):

> I was wondering whether it is guaranteed that, in both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, `sizeof(int)` is always equal to `sizeof(void*)`

No.

> I need to know whether it is always guaranteed that a `long int` can accommodate the bits of an `int` and a `void*` together

No. A quick proof is to consider that `sizeof(long int) == sizeof(int)` on *many* modern platforms, probably including the one you're using.

The more important question is *why* you think you "need to know" this; the fact that you're asking such questions makes me concerned that your code is likely to be ... wobbly.

Comment: To give an example for the first "no": Using gcc `sizeof(int)` is 4 on 64-bit platforms (whereas `sizeof(void*)` is 8 of course).

Answer (score 2):

The size of an int is implementation dependent and though it may turn out to be equal to the size of a pointer in many systems, there is no guarantee.

If you decide you need code to depend on this, you can include something such as:

```
if (sizeof(int) != sizeof(void *))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: size assumptions are invalid; this program cannot continue.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Alas, no - the preprocessor doesn't know what something's size is. I'll edit; thanks.

Comment: Personally I don't like assert() as I've seen it #if'd out of non-debug releases too often.

Comment: why not `static_assert`? this assumption won't change at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Recent C99 standard provides a `<stdint.h>` header defining an `intptr_t`  integral type guaranteed to have the same size as pointers.

On my Debian/AMD64/Sid, `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, but `sizeof(void*)` and `sizeof(intptr_t)` and `sizeof(long)` are all 8 bytes.