# Combining an int with a void*

Tags: c++, int, sizeof, void

I need to combine an int with a void*. I was thinking of doing it like :

```
long int lint = ((int)integer<<(sizeof(void*)*8)) | ((void*)ptr);
```

but [according to my previous message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244413/is-sizeofint-always-equal-to-sizeofvoid), a long int won't suffice.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

*PS. Some people will ask why on earth I might want to do this. Well, I am developing a generic events system (dispatch/listen) that caters for countless different cases. I will post code when it's ready...*

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to store a value which might be either an int or a void pointer?

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, it's hopelessly non-portable in that form. Why aren't you using a plain old `struct`?

Comment: What's wrong with defining a `struct` that holds an `int` and a `void*`?

Comment: If I read your code right, you'd need an (at least) 96 bit integer type for this to work in 64 bit code. There is no such type in standard C++. Some compilers might offer a 128 bit integer type, but this wil always be a non-standard extension. As others have said, a struct is the way to go.

Comment: @bill - Whatever you are trying to achieve you are going about it in the wrong way. It is too complex, non-portable and looks messy and unreadable. Why not use a pointer to a `struct` or `union` or a combination of both. Easier to understand, portable and just as efficent as fiddling about bit shift (probably more so).

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use a struct is because I *was hoping* that C++ had built-in types that would cater for this, i.e. types that are double the size of max(sizeof(int), sizeof(void*)). What about **long double**, would that always suffice? :-)

Comment: @BillKotsias Does `std::pair<int,void*>` count as a built-in type?

Comment: @hvd No, I can't compare both values to another pair with a single instruction. A single compare instruction would be super fast and exactly what I am looking for...

Comment: @BillKotsias: `long double`s aren't portable either, MSVC treats them as `double`s.

Comment: @ BillKotsias C++ is an almost complete superset of C, and the **built in** way to do this in C is with a struct.  Stop trying to make things harder on yourself.

Comment: @BillKotsias That's not guaranteed to be available for any type, not even `char`.

Comment: OK people, you have convinced me. I'll go for a struct and let the compilers do the hard work (of optimizing) for me

Comment: Iirc, x86 cannot compare integers > 32 bits in a single instruction anyway (without SSE), same for > 64 bits on x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm shouldn't it be something like:

```
long long res = ((long long)integer<<(sizeof(void*))) | ((long long)ptr);
```

Thit will still only work for 32 bit pointers and will not work for 64 bit. There is no built-in type that will fit such arithmetics.

Comment: My experience is that if it looks ugly it is the wrong solution. The above looks ugly.

Comment: I agree and if I had to combine a pointer with an int I would not suggest this approach. However the question was how to combine them in this way so I am only pointing out the errors in what he proposes.

Comment: @EdHeal It's the "assembler" way of thinking. :-)

Comment: @BillKotsias, but you write in `c++`, not `assembler`.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Sometimes, it helps to think in assembler and write in other languages - speed-wise that is.

Comment: @BillKotsias, how can this code will increase speed? It's doubtful. But a looot of problems when you move to 64bit are guarantied. You should not ague with language you use. You should use rules it states, or move to another language

Answer (score 3):

**The only answer is to use struct**

Don't try to be smarter than compiler. Don't perform premature optimization. Write simplest and clearest code and only after you see it too slow, perform low-level optimization

Struct are better here because:

1. It is portable
2. It safe
3. It is c++ ideomatic.
4. *It is faster*.

Let me bust your myths about comparing speed of long long and struct. As you know, all ways to optimize your code starts with profiling. Lets make simple program and measure comparing speed of vectors of `long long` and `struct S`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

struct S
{
    unsigned int a;
    void* b;

    bool operator==(const S& other)  const
    {
        return a == other.a && b == other.b;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
int count_eq(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (Iterator i  = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        for (Iterator j  = i + 1; j != end; ++j) {
            result += *i == *j;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename Iterator>
void mesure(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    long long t0 = GetTickCount();
    int res = count_eq(begin, end);
    long long t1 = GetTickCount();
    std::cout << "result: " << res <<"; Time: "<<(t1-t0)<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int Size = 20000;
    std::vector<unsigned long long> l;
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        l.push_back(i% (Size/10));
    }

    std::vector<S> s;
    for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
        S el;
        el.a = j% (Size/10);
        el.b = 0;
        s.push_back(el);
    }

    mesure(l.begin(), l.end());
    mesure(s.begin(), s.end()); 
}
```

Lets check results:

```
>g++ src.cpp -O3
>a
result: 90000; Time: 327
result: 90000; Time: 188
```

Yes, `struct` with custom `operator ==` 1.5 times faster.

Comment: No it's not! http://ideone.com/KiNtH I suppose your compiler optimizes it because you always set void* = 0, so it skips that comparison.

Comment: It is comiler specific. Same ideone shows opposit result for `c++` profile, as my compiler: http://ideone.com/uBkPE

Comment: @BillKotsias, also how can you be sure, that ideone does not use 64bit platform, where your code faster, but incorrect?

Comment: @BillKotsias: We don't know what optimization settings ideone is using. On my system (g++ 4.6.1), the struct version is faster with -O2 and -O3, but not with -O1.

Answer (score 0):

you should use something like `uint_least64_t`, available from `stdint.h`, of course it cannot hold pointers from 64 bits systems, for that you would need to use a struct as many people have mentioned in the comments.

Though the way you are using the pointers seems weird, it looks like you don't even need to use `void*` for what you are doing, nevermind the fact that you could to the same thing with polymorphism (for the event system you described).

Comment: It's guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer, and at the same time extremely unlikely to be able to hold more than that, so it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: As others have pointed out, it's very well possible that no large enough type exists, if you're dealing with a platform where pointers are already 64-bits. Not `uint_least64_t` either, which on such platforms is probably a typedef for the same type as `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @Hvd: was putting that in as you posted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a data structure that can store either an int or a void pointer, use a [union](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15).  A union will be the size of the largest value it contains.  You can do something like this:

```
typedef union {
    void *data,
    int *value
} myUnion_t;

myUnion_t storage;
int num = 10;

// if you want to store a void pointer
storage.data = &num;

// if you want to store an int
storage.value = num;
```

Keep in mind a union is not a struct and should only store one value at a time.

Comment: He wants one value to hold both at the same time, so a union isn't the right answer (a regular struct is).