# Is int * x equivalent to int * int x?

Tags: c

When writing `int * x`, is there an implicit `int` for the type of the pointer, so that implicitly it is `int * int x`?

Comment: A pointer is not an int…

Comment: `int * int x` means absolutely nothing.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my ealier comment...

There is no single pointer data type in C.  Instead, you have multiple "pointer to `T`" datatypes - an `int *` is a distinct data type from a `char *`, which is a distinct data type from a `double *`, which is a distinct data type from a `void (*)(...)`, which is a distinct data type from a `long (*)[N]`, etc.

*Even if all pointer types have the same size and representation* (which is the case on most platforms, but not guaranteed), the semantics will differ.  Assume the declarations

```
int  *ip =  (int *) 0x00004000;
char *cp = (char *) 0x00004000;
```

Both `ip` and `cp` start out with the same value (pointing to address 0x00004000, which is probably not valid).  If I execute the statements

```
ip++; // or ip = ip + 1;
cp++; // or cp = cp + 1;
```

the resulting values of `ip` and `cp` will be different; `ip` will contain the address of the next *integer* (either 0x00004002 for a 16-bit integer or 0x00004004 for a 32-bit integer), but `cp` will contain the address of the next *character* (0x00004001).  Pointer arithmetic is dependent on the base type of the pointer, so operations on integer pointers will yield different results from operations on pointers to other types.

It is possible for different pointer types to have different sizes.  Think of a word-addressed architecture, where the basic unit of memory could be 16 bits wide, or 24, or 32, or 36.  Any pointer to a type that occupied a full word would be N bits wide, but `char *` types would require some extra bits to point to specific characters within the word (unless you decided `char` values should also occupy the full word).

Answer (score 3):

A pointer **is** a type. It's not an integer, it's not a float, it's not a double, it's not a char, it's not a long.
What it holds depends on the architecture of the machine for which you have compiled your code.

When you do arithmetics on pointers (`+=`, `-=`) the result is not the same as when you do it with integers.

You'll also notice that `char *` and `int *` are distinct types. You can probably cast between both, but when you increment them, unless `sizeof int == 1` you get a different result.

What you probably want to know is what size the pointer occupies. Try then the following:

```
printf("%u %u %u %u\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(int), sizeof(int *), sizeof(long));
```

Note that different types of pointers [can have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer) different sizes.

Comment: Could you do `sizeof(*)`, or something similar, instead of `sizeof(int *)`? [Because `int` in `sizeof(int *)` is redundant/useless.]

Comment: @Randomblue: no. You can `typedef int *int_ptr` and use `sizeof(int_ptr)`.

Comment: @Randomblue: the int is *not* redundant or useless; pointers to int may well be different sizes from pointers to other types.  There is no single "pointer" type; there are multiple "pointer to T" types.

Comment: @Brian Roach: [Pointers can have different sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941793/what-is-guaranteed-about-the-size-of-a-function-pointer)

Comment: I hate "can" vs. "do" arguments, so I'll retract that statement since I can't edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

No.  `int * x` declares `x` as a variable of type "pointer to objects of type `int`".

Comment: Why am I suddenly having flashbacks to "Who's on first?".

Comment: @Randomblue: A pointer is not an `int`. Pointer arithmetics differ from `int` arithmetics (`p + 1` ≠ `i + 1`), etc. Pointers are types by themselves. If you wonder how many bytes they are stored on, then use `sizeof x`. Maybe you get the same as `sizeof int` but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Brian, another 8 minutes lost to laughing at You Tube clips.

Comment: @Duck - amazing how well that sketch holds up, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

No. Pointers are not necessarily the same size as an `int`. This is particularly relevant on some architectures and if you also take into account things like function pointers.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Aha. And the notation is `*` for pointer types? Thanks, I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit *anything* when you write `int *x`.  `x` is a pointer, but it doesn't point to anything.  The type of `x` is `int *`.

`int * int x` isn't legal syntax at all.

Comment: it's rather dangling. It *could* point to something valid if you're really lucky.

Comment: Yes, but even then, relying on undefined behaviour is arguably a poor idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something which tends to be confusing when learning C is the `*` character. It actually has two entirely different uses:

1. To create a **Pointer Variable**
2. Used as an **Indirection Operator**

You can get a **Pointer Address** (memory address) of a variable, and assign it to a Pointer Variable, by using the **Address-of** `&` operator.

```
// Using * to create a Pointer Variable (pointer to an int):
int * intPtr;

// Using the & Address-of Operator to get the Pointer Address (memory address) of a variable, and assign it to a Pointer Variable:
int x = 10;
intPtr = &x;

// Printing the value of `x`, which is 10:
printf("%d\n", x);

// Using the Indirection Operator *, on a Pointer Variable, to perform indirection:
*intPtr = 20;

// Above, we modified the value of `x` using indirection via `intPtr`. So now `x` is equal to 20, and not 10:
printf("%d\n", x);
```

printf() output:

```
10
20
```

As others have mentioned, `int * int x;` is not valid in C.