# Cannot understand return value of sizeof()

Tags: c, malloc

I have this in my code:

```
int x = 4;
char* array = malloc(x*sizeof(char));
size_t arraysize = sizeof (array);
printf("arraysize: %zu\n", arraysize);
```

This code prints out,

> arraysize: 8

Why is it 8 and not 4? (Since 4*sizeof(char) = 4 * 1)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: Yes I've meant zu.I've changed it. Well,it's the first time I am pointed to that site, thank you for the info! You can calm down by the way, I am a student learning to program, and yes it was the first time I got this problem! So once again, do calm down!

Comment: It returns ptr size. Even if you make x value as 1000 it will return only 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`array` is a pointer in your code. `sizeof(array)` therefore returns the size of that pointer in C bytes (reminder: C's bytes can have more than 8 bits in them).

So, 8 is your pointer size.

Also, the correct type specifier for `size_t` in printf()'s format strings is `%zu`.

Comment: *C's bytes can have more than 8 bits in them?* Is it ?? I need a link to read

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan [Here's one](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html).

Answer (score 3):

`array` is a pointer, hence it will be size of a pointer(`sizeof(void *)` or `sizeof(char *)`), and not `sizeof(char)` as you might expect. It seems that you are using 64bit computer.

Comment: You mean sizeof(*char) which is sizeof(*void) ?

Comment: `sizeof(void *)` or `sizeof(char *)` @Patashu

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, is it not sizeof(int) almost everytime? The exceptions are always around but it is usually sizeof(int) or `intptr_t`? And I have mentioned both in the answer.

Comment: @Aniket Almost, but not everytime/everywhere. In 64-bit programs on x86 systems you typically have 32-bit ints and 64-bit pointers.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze ok edited my answer and removed the reference to `sizeof(int)`

Comment: `void *` and `char *` are required to have the same representation, so their sizes are the same.

Comment: [**sizeof (int) == sizeof (void*)?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void)

Comment: @Aniket Are all pointers the same size? *Hint: Refer to [this page](http://www.c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) in your answer.*

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` doesn't have a return value because it isn't a function, it's a C language construct -- consider the fact that you can write `sizeof array` without the parentheses. As a C language construct, its value is based entirely on compile-time information. It has no idea how big your array is, only how big the `array` pointer variable is. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof for complete coverage of the subject.

Comment: Are you trying to say `sizeof` expressions are always evaluated during translation?

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(array)` returns the size of a pointer.

Comment: Only if `array` *is* a pointer. Given `char array[999];`, `sizeof(array)` is 999.

Answer (score -2):

You are calculating the size of the full array (4*sizeof(char))
But you spect to know the number of items on the array (4).

You can do

> size_t arraysize = sizeof (array)/sizeof(char);

It will return 8/2 = 4

Comment: sizeof(char) is *always* 1 -- the C Standard requires that. See other answers for the correct response.