# Is sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)?

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

Does C guarantee that `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)`? If not, why is it used so extensively in Linux kernel source code?

I looked at [sizeof (int) == sizeof (void*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void) but that talks about `sizeof(int)` vs `sizeof(void *)`.

Comment: Q: What makes you think the answer for "long" would be any different than the answer for "int"???  Same answer, same reason :)

Comment: Simple answer: No

Comment: Can you give an example of how it is used in the linux kernel?

Answer (score 11):

No, the C standard does not guarantee that `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)`.

In practice, on Windows 64-bit systems, the values are `4` for `sizeof(long)` and `8` for `sizeof(void *)`.  This design conforms to the C standard.  See also [What is the bit-size of `long` on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384672/15168)

Those implementing the Linux kernel have presumably decided that they'll never port the code to a system that follows the Windows 64-bit LLP64 (`long long` and pointers are 64-bit quantities) system, and therefore don't need to concern themselves with whether the sizes are different.  Both the 32-bit systems (ILP32) and the 64-bit systems (LP64) *do* have `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)`.  But the C standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: BTW: Windows is irrelevant.It was designed ot be.

Comment: IIRC [and I could be wrong about this], the reason windows went with LLP64 was because it originally had code where `int` was 16 bits [8086 with DOS and 386 with win16]. So, a lot of software, to get a 32 bit number, used `long`. This was fine until we get to a 64 bit machine. Then, to maintain backwards compatibility they chose the model that broke the least amount of software.

Comment: @CraigEstey — what you describe matches pretty well with my understanding of how Windows ended up where it is.

Comment: "Port the code to a system that..." is missing the point - here, Linux **is the system** and *its ABI*, not C, defines `long` as having the same size as pointers.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Linux is a freestanding system designed for x86. The size of long and the ABI for writing the Linux OS is strictly speaking determined by the specific x86 compiler port. Porting Linux to a different x86 compiler isn't gonna happen, simply because the code base is married with gcc, relying heavily on gcc-specific behavior and non-standard extensions.

Comment: @Lundin: The target platform (here, "Linux x86") defines its ABI. A compiler that does not match that ABI is a compiler for a different platform.

Comment: pointer must be 64bit quantities in 64bit architectures.  What can chenge size is the size of a long.  Again, they don't need to be the same.  In linux 64bit long is 64 bit, and pointers are 64bit also.

Answer (score 3):

The only guarantees are:

- `void *` and `char *` have the same size and alignment;
- Pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as pointers to their unqualified equivalents (i.e., `sizeof (const int *) == sizeof (int *)`);
- All `struct` pointer types have the same size and alignment;
- All `union` pointer types have the same size and alignment;

That's it.

If Linux kernel developers are writing code that assumes `sizeof (long) == sizeof (void *)`, then they've decided to limit which platforms they're going to support.  Which is absolutely fine - you don't have to support every oddball architecture out there.